# GWT .properties comments?

Tags: gwt, internationalization

In GWT, you can have a .properties file that lists key value pairs:

```
foo = bar
baz = batz
```

Is there a way to do comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `#`

```
# These are my key/val pairs
foo=bar
baz=batz
```

You can also use `!` but it's not common practice in my experience.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties